# JavaFX Charts - NoSuchMethodError on flatMap when trying to add data to a LineChart

Tags: java, maven, javafx, fxml, flatmap

I'm trying to create a LineChart in JavaFX and everything works except adding data to the chart. It works when there is no data added to the chart but as soon as I try to add data it gives me a long error basically saying that it can't find the flatMap method.

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty.flatMap(java.util.function.Function)'`

I've read somewhere that it can be because of my JavaFX version but I can't seem to figure it out.

Java code:

```
package GUI;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

public class GUIStockLinegraphController {
    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> chart;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yAxis;

    public void initialize(){
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series.setName("Test Chart");

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1, 2)); //The error comes up when this line is added

        chart.getData().add(series);
    }
}
```

FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<LineChart fx:id="chart" xmlns="http://javafx.com/fxml/11"
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
           fx:controller="GUI.GUIStockLinegraphController"
           layoutX="5.0" layoutY="10.0"
           prefHeight="233.0" prefWidth="870.0" >
    <xAxis>
        <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" fx:id="xAxis"/>
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis side="LEFT" fx:id="yAxis"/>
    </yAxis>

</LineChart>
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/F:/chartsDemo/target/classes/GUI/Stock-linegraph.fxml
/F:/chartsDemo/target/classes/GUI/Stock-view.fxml:59

    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2727)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2697)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2568)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1160)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:759)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2858)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2654)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2568)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2536)
    at com.example.demo/GUI.GUIMainApplication.start(GUIMainApplication.java:41)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@22/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml@22/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2693)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty.flatMap(java.util.function.Function)'
    at javafx.controls@22/javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Data$4.invalidated(XYChart.java:1371)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.controls@22/javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Data.setNode(XYChart.java:1406)
    at javafx.controls@22/javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.createSymbol(LineChart.java:531)
    at javafx.controls@22/javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.seriesAdded(LineChart.java:424)
    at javafx.controls@22/javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.lambda$new$1(XYChart.java:164)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:113)
    at com.example.demo/GUI.GUIStockLinegraphController.initialize(GUIStockLinegraphController.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    ... 24 more
Exception running application GUI.GUIMainApplication
```

I tried changing around the Maven dependencies but that didn't fix anything.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This seems like a version mismatch between the `javafx.controls` module and the `javafx.base` module. That stack trace and your POM indicate you are using `javafx.controls` version 22, but there is no version for `javafx.base` in the stack trace, which is odd. Can you provide a [mre]? Which version of Java are you using? Which vendor did you get your Java installation? Can you show your full POM? What does `mvn dependency:tree` output?

Comment: @SedJ601 That's what a `LoadException` looks like when an error occurs while loading a nested FXML file (i.e., `fx:include`). But the problem is not in the FXML file or the controller, as the `initialize` method of the nested FXML's controller is being invoked just fine. `NoSuchMethodError`s between JavaFX modules is a strong indicator of a version mismatch.

Comment: @Slaw is correct: this is a version mismatch. The latest version of `XYChart.Data` calls `flatMap()` on the `series` (an `ObjectProperty`, which is part of the `javafx.base` module) to compute and configure display nodes. The `flatMap()` method was introduced in JavaFX 19. So somehow you have a `javafx.base` version <19. *Why* is not clear; `javafx.base` is indirectly a dependency of `javafx.controls`. My best guess (and it is a guess) is that somehow `controlsfx` is causing the mismatch. Try excluding `javafx.controls` from the `org.controlsfx` dependency.

Comment: That said, I cannot reproduce the error with the dependencies you list. I can only reproduce it if I have an explicit dependency for `javafx.base` with an earlier version. Post a [mre] with the complete `pom.xml` and a complete working example that generates the error.